# how to use php strip tags with img tag exceptions

Tags: php, html, sql

You likely think this question is already asked. However this question is different. I want to strip all tags except: `<img src='smilies/smilyOne.png'>`, and `<img src='smilies/smilyTwo.png'>`
Here is my existing code:

```
$message = stripslashes(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']), "<img>?"));
```

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Check the [documentation for `strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) - you are using it wrong at the moment.

Comment: Do you know if you can use strip tags with html tags with attributes? Thanks by the way.

Comment: You can't specify attributes in `strip_tags` -- your best bet for solving your problem is to strip all but the image tags, and then selectively strip out the img tags using a regular expression. Alternatively, you can use DOMDocument (or similar XML/HTML parser) to parse the text and selectively remove image tags.

Comment: I'm not too good with regex. Also I'm wanting to save likely 10 or so images.

Comment: Do you think images are a security threat? Maybe I don't have to strip any images if that is the case?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing with your script or where your data is from, so I can't say!

Comment: The data is a message being inserted into a database. Sent in via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and its related classes to parse the html, find the image elements, and then remove those elements that don't have the correct `src` attribute. It uses a simple regular expression to match the src attribute:

```
/^smilies\/smily(One|Two)\.png$/
```

`^` is the beginning of the string and `$` is the end; `/` and `.` are both special characters in regular expressions, so they are escaped with a backslash; `(One|Two)` means match `One` or `Two`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);  // your text to be filtered is in $html

// iterate through all the img elements in $html
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {

    # eliminate images with no "src" attribute
    if (! $img->hasAttribute('src')) {
        $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
    }
    # eliminate images where the src is not smilies/smily(One|Two).png
    elseif (1 !== preg_match("/^smilies\/smily(Two|One)\.png$/",
      $img->getAttribute("src"))) {
        $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
    }
    // otherwise, the image is OK!
}
$output = $dom->saveHTML();

# now strip out anything that isn't an <img> tag
$html = strip_tags($output, "<img>");

echo "html now: $html\n\n";
```

Comment: Do you think images are a security threat? Maybe I don't have to strip any images if that is the case?

Comment: @user3234267 that is really a separate question, and you should do some research on it. If the code I provided works, please click the tick next to my answer and the up arrow--that's how to express thanks on Stack Overflow.